# d3.js line not drawing because of x function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I have this code -

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0,width]);
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([maxVal["quantity-sold"], minVal["quantity-sold"]]).range([0,height]);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) { 
            console.log("D");
            console.log(d);
            return 1})
        .y(function(d) { return yScale(d["quantity-sold"])});
```

The console.log("D") does not seem to be running, and no points are showing.

Why?

This is how I've tried adding the line

```
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class","line")
        .attr("d", function(d){ console.log(d)});
```

Comment: Are you using `line` anywhere?

Comment: er no... when I try and use it like this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

I get a cannot read property length of undefined - I've posted that code up

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't use `line`.

Comment: Where do you call .data or .datum

Answer (score 0):

As the example shows:

You must call

> > svg.append("path").datum(dataInArrayFormat) ....(rest of call)

Using .data (or .datum, which should be used for static data because the enter/exit isn't computed) gently feeds your array of points into the d3.svg.line function.

Basically, you're not feeding it any data, therefore, the console.logs are not being displayed. It's not the x function's fault.